# Terraform accessing secure information

Tags: security, terraform

**Setting**
I have a terraform blueprint that has some curl commands in a remote exec

The curl commands needs a user name and password.

So, in Terraform, I had a variable without a default value that asked the user for their username and password. Then the curl command would use those inputted values at runtime. This way I don't store usernames and passwords on github.

But, I think this may be insecure. Wouldn't the username and password now be stored in the terraform state file?

**Question**

How should I use terraform to execute a curl command that requires sensitive information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing something in a provisioner then that's not stored in the state file because Terraform makes no attempt to track what happens there. You should probably consider your state files sensitive anyway for when you have resources that store sensitive state information (such as database passwords) and think about how to encrypt/manage access to them.

Comment: If I set a variable in the variables.tf file at runtime, you are saying that it won't be stored in the terraform state file because the state file only saves information concerning the resources?

Comment: Yes but you can easily test it by applying your changes and then listing and showing the state or just looking at the raw state file.